# Stretch progress bar right up to where the original image starts

Tags: android

I have a rather weird request.

I have this image which displays the company logo, the image is a 9 patch designed so that only the rightmost part is stretched. On top of that part, a progress bar will be placed.
To fit all screens, the progress bar needs to stretch to cover only the part of the image that was stretched, nothing more or it will hide the company logo.

This is how it should look:
[image]

This is how it looks on a smaller screen:
[image]

The problem here is that the progress bar has a fixed width, which obviously does not work for all form factor widths out there.
So, is there a way to have the progress bar dynamically cover up the logo image right up to where the logo is?

I guess I could just on creation get the width of the screen, and more or less calculate a ratio, but it seems to ugly and inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I went with the ugly (maybe only) route.

```
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        int width = size.x;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = progressBar.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = width * 2/3;
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout` and set `ProgressBar` width as **Match Parent**. Put your company logo below the `ProgressBar` and use property `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`. I guess this will give you the desired effect.

Comment: The company logo is not separate from the image the progress bar is on top of.